# Facebook upload photo to timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

### => Description

So far I have made a script which uploads image to my Facebook timeline. I've generated a user access token from my App and I'm uploading photos from the App generated user access token..

### => Problem

I'm using /me/photos end point to upload photos on my timeline. But the problem is that, instead of creating separate post for every photo I upload, it is creating an album which is quite annoying. 
Is there any way to upload every photo separately ?

### => Extras

The Facebook App name which I'm using to upload photo is Abhishek's Meme ^.^

### => Screenshot

https://prnt.sc/ka8buc

### => Code

```
$privacy = array(
    'value' => 'EVERYONE' //public
);

$data = [
  'message' => 'TEST CAPTION',
  'privacy'=> $privacy,
  'photo' => 'test.jpg'
];

try {
  $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, $accesstoken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Comment: as far as I know this is the standard on facebook.. I tried uploading an image on my timeline (regular not with the API) and it also creates an album..

Comment: You’re aware that you have only about another week to “enjoy” this, right? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp Did you try to upload an image one by one ? Then it won't create an album.